# Problem with identity scaffolding in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, identity, asp.net-core-identity

I am trying to implement identity auth to my project but it's not creating an `applicationdb` class like it used to. I am new to coding so I am sorry if it looks dumb

[Z](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Pp8.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcUUI.png)

I was expecting to get the db class like it used to create before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to implement identity auth to my project but it's not
> creating an applicationdb class like it used to. I am new to coding so
> I am sorry if it looks dumb

You haven't specified, which version of .NET you are using. However, in latest version or in [.NET 8 Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-without-existing-authorization) has moved away from a single pre-defined `ApplicationDbContext` class. Instead, it encourages developers to define their own DbContext while adding the Identity scaffholding.

You can define your own ApplicationDbContext by yourself before adding Identity or at the same time while adding identity within your project.

So, while you would click for adding Identity within your project, it would give you the option for DbContext configuration.

You can do as following:

[image]

Or you can create manually as following:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Output:

After successfull creation, you should have following output:

[image]

**Note:** Make sure, that you have the necessary NuGet packages installed for Identity. In ASP.NET Core 8, you typically need `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` package. Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-without-existing-authorization), if you want to study more.